# ¿Cómo consigo URL de política de privacidad en una página de Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Estoy intentando usar un webhook en una nueva Fanpage, he seguido el tutorial de un foro pero en la opción para hacer pública la aplicación me aparece esto:

> Debes proporcionar una URL de política de privacidad válida para publicar tu aplicación.

¿Alguien sabe donde consigo esa URL? o ¿qué es a lo que se refiere?

Comment: Esa la debes colocar en tu sitio web, en alguna parte como dominio.com/about-privacy

Answer (score 6):

Ese link tu lo debes tener en tu sito web, te explico:

En tu sitio web debes tener una política de privacidad una pagina dedicada a ello.

Por ejemplo:
yo tengo un sitio web `ejemplo.com` y en el menú de mi pagina tengo algunos links, que son los siguientes:

```
<a href="ejemplo.com/nosotros">Nosotros</a>

<a href="ejemplo.com/contacto">Contacto</a>
```

Y el último de mis links es:

```
<a href="ejemplo.com/politica-de-privacidad">nuestra política de privacidad</a>
```

El link que **facebook** te esta pidiendo es ese

> ejemplo.com/politica-de-privacidad

Debes explicar en esta pagina qué información de los usuario estás utilizando y qué haces con ella, si buscas en google puedes encontrar mucha información acerca de cómo redactar correctamente una política de privacidad.

Answer (score 4):

> Actualización: Puedes usar el siguiente link que te ayudará a generar una página de privacidad rápidamente **https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/**

Para crear uno rápido entra a este link: `https://politicadeprivacidadplantilla.com`

Solamente debes poner el nombre de tu App, luego dar siguiente, descargar y finalmente exportar como html:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Copias y pegas en en un servidor gratuito que tengas (FTP) en mi caso use uno que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez tengas eso, copias la url de tu servidor y lo pegas en **URL de la política y privacidad**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Listo!!

> Nota: Si en caso no tienes un hosting gratuito y no quieres gastar mucho, una práctica manera es crearte una cuenta aqui: **https://www.000webhost.com/**